# Enough space, downloads most of the app, then says not enough space

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

So I'm trying to install a little game called Xcom: Enemy Within, Google Play store downloads most of the App- I'd say 99% at least...then it gives me an error and says there's not enough memory- I have about 338 MB left after that.

MORESO- I have an external mini SD card that I want to put this on but it won't allow me to download directly to it.(Which- I must say is a dumb design oversight that...well the ability to do that has been around since Windows XP guys come on) so long-term it isn't going to be that big of an issue. What can I do?

Comment: OH-! and I forgot to mention, the data it downloads is still on the hard-drive even though it says there isn't enough space- And for reference I have a brand new Moto-E

Comment: The installed size is almost always bigger than the download size shown in the Play Store. The problem is simple, you don't have enough space on your phone. Either upgrade to a phone with sufficient internal space or free up some space.

Comment: You've asked two questions which doesn't help the reader to answer. Please [edit] and move your other question as new question here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing Play Store's cache and data and see if that helps. To do this, goto

`*Settings > Apps (or Manage Applications)*`

Swipe to    `All`

Then tap on Google Play Store> Clear Data
Reboot and try the download once again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually almost every good game these days requires an additional file, which is probably used by the developers to store some data on the phone and also to probably unpack all the compressed files. Try having at least 1 GB of your memory free and retry the download, it should not have any issues

Comment: `Try having at least 1 GB of your memory free` -- Any reason why only 1 GB? Is this based on your experience or you read it somewhere? Please mention the source if you read it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me I just delete some.of the android apps your phone comes with that you never use like the music app and video app, duo the weather app then download it. Then I move the file to my sd card  havent found one good app for this that isn't virus free or doesnt slow your phone down. Hopefully this either helps or you already currently do this.